# Excluding files of particular extension using DIR command on windows command line

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, dir

if i want to see e.g. files of a particular extension only using dir listing, i can do that using the command:

```
DIR *.txt
```

And it shows all files with `.txt` extension.
Now i want to know is there any command with wich i can exclude certain extensions?
For example, i don't want to see any file with extension `.exe`, how can i do that?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

DIR wont allow what you are trying to do. However DIR along with FINDSTR can solve this.

e.g. The following ignores all .txt files in the DIR listing.

```
dir | findstr /v /i "\.txt$"
```

Comment: you may want to use `dir /b | findstr /v /i "\.txt$"` because `dir` will output the  header and the possible incorrect files and folders count at the end

Comment: Why `findstr` over just `find`?

Comment: Because find searches for text and findstr supports regexes I suggested Findstr. If you just want to search an exact string find would work fine too.

Answer (score 14):

```
dir /B | find /V ".txt"
```

This would list all files and find would filter out anything that doesn't contain ".txt". It's far from perfect, but maybe it's enough :)

Comment: No need for `/B`, I would say, but I prefer this answer as long as I don't see the need for 'findstr` (the actual accepted one).

Answer (score 3):

### It depends on your command interpreter.

Microsoft's `cmd` doesn't have such a facility, as you can see from the other answers where one has to post-process the output of `dir`. However, the tool from [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com./tccle_cmd_replacement.html) has this feature.  It is called a [file exclusion range](http://jpsoft.com./help/filexranges.htm) and is used like this for the example in your question:

```
dir /[!*.exe] *
```

Comment: Thank you, but i think this tool run as standalone program. I am making my application where i run external process using windows shell or bash in ubuntu, so this tool will not fit, If they provide cmd line switches then it will be useful.

Comment: The aforegiven clearly **is** a command-line switch.  Read the hyperlinked documentation.  Of course, in most programming languages it is fairly silly to go to the length of using the shell for [obtaining directory contents](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=list+directory), and you are on the wrong StackExchange for writing applications.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, that's true but it is a workaround for scanning those directories which require Elevation and i don't want to make my code trigger UAC prompt, when i can get results from cmd prompt without requiring higher privilege.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, define a macro using `DOSKEY`. I excluded directories and ignored case – YMMV. Also, `/B` seems like the most reasonable `DIR` option for filtering, `/D` and `/W` being inappropriate for the task, and the long formats `/N` (default) and `/X` containing, in some cases, additional text after the filename (for symlinks). Check it out on the command line:

```
DOSKEY  FIR=DIR/B/A-D^|FINDSTR /VIE $*
DOSKEY FLIR=DIR/X/A-D^|FINDSTR /VIE $*
```

`FIR` for *filtered* `DIR`, get it? :) And `FLIR` for the long version if needed. Then use it like this:

```
fir .jpg
flir jpg
fir "jpg htm"
```

The latter is because of how `FINDSTR` reads patterns supplied as arguments, as documented in the `/?`. Only the first argument is treated as a pattern, additional ones are interpreted as file names, even when running in a pipe.

I prefer `FINDSTR` over plain `FIND` because it has the funky `/E` switch which filters only at the end of the line, which seems preferable when filtering by file extension (but again, YMMV).

The handy [SS64 site](https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html) explains how to set up macros in a `TXT` file for permanent reuse. Beware, no caret `^` to escape special characters for macros stored in a text file.

To understand the basics of how macros ("Console aliases") work under the hood, read [Eryk Sun's brief comments on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50940977).